# Call function in a component from a service in Angular 5? Without using @input or @output

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have to make a call to a function in a component from an angular service.

How do I go about doing this?

On success of a web service call, I want to call a function in the component

Comment: Are you using the service in the same component?

Comment: Its not a good practice mate instead you return an Http Observable from service subscribe in component and invoke the method inside subscribe callback.

Comment: [Angular StyleGuide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#services)

Comment: What do you mean by **Without using @input or @output**. If you have some code to share please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for that @Vikas will give that a try

Answer (score 1):

We can easily call a function of a component from an injected service

Look at this [stackblidtz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-http-hktxvx?file=app/app.component.ts), where the function `showAlert` is called from  the service **ones we subscribe and got the results**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IProduct } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './products.service';
import { Http , Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component ({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: '<table border="1"><tr *ngFor="let elem of iproducts"><td>{{ elem.ProductID }}</td><td>{{ elem.ProductName }}</td></tr></table>',
   providers: [ProductService]
})

export   class   AppComponent  {
   iproducts: IProduct[];
   constructor(private _product: ProductService) {
   }

   ngOnInit() : void {
      this._product.getproducts()
      .subscribe( (iproducts) => {
        this.iproducts = iproducts;
        this.showAlert(); //call showAlert function <------
      });
   }

   showAlert() {
     console.log('we have the products !');
   }
}
```

**Note:** The intent of a service is to be injected to the component, that we can use it and use all the business logic there **and not to import the component in the service and call a method of a component in the service**

Comment: I want to call a function in the component, from the service file.

Comment: @John: You cannot do that. you can do that only from member functions of the component itself like a constructor or the subscribe after calling your service.

Comment: @John go for this approach this is recommended one

Comment: @John  Logic can be reused by multiple components when placed within a service and exposed via a function.

Comment: The intent of a service is to be injected to the component, that we can use it and use all the business logic there and **NOT to import the component in the service** and call a method of a component in the service.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the step:

- import service into component
- create an instance by the help of constructor.
- now you can call function into component by the help of instance.

So you can follow below process to call service function to component.

```js
Example:-

component file
==============

import { CustomerService } from './../../service/customer.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'add_additional_contact.html'
})
export class AddAdditionalContactComponent implements OnInit { 
    constructor( 
        private addcontactservice: CustomerService 
    ) {}

ngOninit(){
this.addcontactservice.getCustomerList().subscribe((result) => {});
}
}


service file
==================

import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { StaticData } from './../../common/static_data.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {
public apiUrl = "api URL";
 constructor(
        private http: HttpClient 
    ) { }
getCustomerList(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'addEditCustomerContact', { action: 'list' });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not calling any function in the subscribe call back in your example.

Comment: I want to do the opposite, I want a call a function in the component from the service.

Comment: @John, is a very very bad practice call a function in component from the service. you can create in the service a Subject and emit a value. In your component you subscribe to the subject and in the subscribe call a function, but, please, not inject a component in a service.  think that the service must be autonomous